# Predict Values by using neural net in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm new in using R, but the more I get in thouch with, the more I like it.
Howver, I try to utilze R for artificial neural networks.

My input data is a csv-Table with measured soil properties. 
Phosphorus, pH, clay content, silt content and so on.

The objective is to train an neural network with `neuralnet` and predict Phosphorus (P) by using measured pH, clay content, silt content and so on.

Actually my following script works to train a net, but I don't know, if the script really predicts P by computing the test-dataset with the explaining variables.

Code is below.

```
library(neuralnet)

getwd("F:/Dropbox/Agrar/Fernerkundung_Agrar/ANN_Test/") 
setwd("F:/Dropbox/Agrar/Fernerkundung_Agrar/ANN_Test/")
library(gdata)


# This is a script to train a neural net and test it afterward.
# Objectives are to extimate Phosphorus-Contents in Soil from other variables
# Again. Targetparameter is P (Phosphorus) which has to be estimated from pH, ECa (Soil apparent electrical conductivity) (and later other input variables)

# Traininginput is a CSV-File with measured varaiables P, pH, ECa [here called EC2509 because it was measured in September 25th]
traininginput = read.csv("in.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".")


#Train the neural network
#Going to have 3 hidden layers -> thumb rule input + output variables
#Threshold is a numeric value specifying the threshold for the partial derivatives of the error function as stopping criteria.
# All later considerd parameters are P~ + PH + clay_A + silt_A + sand_A + LS + A_ABAG + TWI + EC2509
# First let's try P and two variables 
net.Phos <- neuralnet(P~PH,traininginput, hidden=3, threshold=0.01, rep = 100) # stepmax = 1000000 will be included later


print(net.Phos)
write.table(net.Phos,"ann_setup.txt", header = TRUE, sep = " ", dec = ".")

#Plot the neural network
png(filename="ANN.png")
pdf(filename="ANN.pdf")
plot(net.Phos)
dev.off()

#Test the neural network: Testdata contains measured variables P, pH, ECa and others. Exactly the same setup than input
testdata = read.csv("testann.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".")
head(testdata)
net.test <- compute(net.Phos, testdata$PH) #Run them through the neural network

#Lets see what properties net.sqrt has
ls(net.Phos)
write.table(net.Phos,"ann_properties.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".")

#Lets see the test results
print(net.test$neurons[[1]])
print(net.test$net.test)


#Lets display a better version of the results
cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata$PH,testdata$P,
    as.data.frame(net.results$net.result[,1]))
colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("PH","Expected P","Neural Net P")
print(cleanoutput)
write.csv(Cleanout,"ann_setup.csv", header = TRUE, sep = " ", dec = ".")
```

Comment: I don't see any mistakes in this code. Why aren't you  sure that script really predicts P?

Comment: I see a problem in this line 
<code>
'net.test <- compute(net.Phos, testdata$PH) #Run them through the neural network'
</code>
I think, when I use 'testdata$PH' then the script predicts P with PH. But it should consider all input trainingdata. In case of 'testdata' (without $), a warning appears. It says something with complex computations.

Comment: What problem? Any warning or error?